kubernates: how to get Load Balancer IP
try to get service loadBalancer url
kubectl get svc --namespace default wordpress-1722945271 --template "{{ range (index .status.loadBalancer.ingress 0) }}{{ . }}{{ end }}"

Got an error
template: output:1:10: executing "output" at <index .status.loadBalancer.ingress>: error calling index: index of untyped nil


If you kubectl get service ... -o yaml, is the field you reference actually there?  In local environments like Kind or Minikube, there may not be a proper load balancer provisioner and that field might not ever get set.

you are right the load balancer is not provisioned status:
loadBalancer: {}

Thamks to david-maze , the solution here is to use minikube tunnel as far as minikube doesn't support LoadBalancer by default
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/.
